# load external pages in div with next and previous anchor buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'm completely new over here and this designer needs some help with programming.
My programming skills are limited to HTML and a very little bit of javascript (I can implement it, but not write it).

Since I've been searching for answers for my problem I could only find those who won't work, are not compatible with all browsers (especialy chrome) or don't know how to edit the scripts to my own demands.

THE PROBLEM:

1. When I click on a link from a UL-list at the page "diensten.html", that link has to load in a div. On the page "diensten.html" where the div is placed, on top and underneath the div should be 2 buttons, up and down. When clicking on i.e. the down button, the page that had loaded into the DIV has to scroll down to the next anchor. The same with the up-button that must scroll back to the previous anchor.

I have a webserver with PHP and mysql enabled, so if it can be done with PHP much easier, it's no problem.

I hope you guys (with your tons of knowledge in programming) have a sort of (easy) way to establish this kind of script?

Thanks a lot

.. and sorry for my bad english as a dutchman ;-)

Greetings,

Comment: It is the scrolling behaviour from div to div that you want to achieve?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would an `iframe` be viable in this scenario? Also, would a scrollbar suffice, instead of two buttons? Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/fSJzm/

Comment: First I want to load a link in a div. Then, outside the div, on the page where the link is, must be 2 buttons up and down, and they have to scroll the loaded page inside the div.

Comment: iframes are not compatible with Chrome browser if I'm right?

Comment: `iframes` are compatible with virtually all browsers now ;) I'll write up a solution.

Comment: @HilhorstReclame `iframes` came out about a decade ago, right along with the nefarious `frame`. `iframes` got a bad rap several years ago, as novice developers were using them only to achieve scrolling capability instead of just using CSS, but they still do exactly what they're meant to do cross-browser. Despite the AJAX hype, when a large amount of HTML content needs to be loaded, `iframes` should be used over `xmlhttprequest`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use jQuery, you can use jQuery's `animate` function to accomplish a smooth-scrolling effect on click or mouseover. Following is an example

```
var step = 25;
var scrolling = false;

// Wire up events for the 'scrollUp' link:
$("#scrollUp").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Animates the scrollTop property by the specified
    // step.
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "-=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function(event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("up");
}).bind("mouseout", function(event) {
    // Cancel scrolling continuously:
    scrolling = false;
});


$("#scrollDown").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "+=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function(event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("down");
}).bind("mouseout", function(event) {
    scrolling = false;
});

function scrollContent(direction) {
    var amount = (direction === "up" ? "-=1px" : "+=1px");
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: amount
    }, 1, function() {
        if (scrolling) {
            // If we want to keep scrolling, call the scrollContent function again:
            scrollContent(direction);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, this to place in de head I assume. But with wich command do I execute the functions? Do I need a <a href.. onclick command?

Comment: Here's a link to the image for a better view.. http://www.hilhorst-reclame.nl/test/images/schets.jpg

Comment: in the mentioned functions i m binding the events with elements with id scrollUp and scrollDown

Answer (score 0):

`iframes` are much better suited for this scenario, assuming that you can use them. With `iframes`, you'll be able to jump to anchor points in the loaded HTML without any special markup. Plus, you'll avoid a lot of headaches that come with loading raw HTML into a div.

I uploaded a working example on jsfiddle, though ironically it doesn't work on jsfiddle; you'll need to download the resources and try them on your own machine.
http://jsfiddle.net/waDUG/5/

Here's how it works. First, the user clicks the "Load Content" button, calling the load() function in Javascript. This will load the page data into the iframe.

The loaded page will have anchor points specified by elements with an id of "anchor#", where "#" is the anchor point number. For example, the loaded page might contain something like this:

```
<h1 id="anchor1">Anchor1:</h1>
...

<h1 id="anchor2">Anchor2:</h1>
...

<h1 id="anchor3">Anchor3:</h1>
...
```

When the Up and Down buttons are pressed, iframe will jump to the next anchor point.

The only catch to this code is that there's no implemented way to determine the last anchor point, but that can easily be hardcoded in if it's a known value.

Comment: Thank, thanks thanks! That brought me closer than I thought I was! I edited the code, because there's a list of links instead of just one button to load a page, so I cleared the loading fuction part. But what I was wondering, is that part needed for the anchor buttons to work? www.hilhorst-reclame.nl/test/test3.html

Comment: @HilhorstReclame Hmm, there appears to be an error on line 78, something about an invalid character?